# How to make Jenkins run my Maven/Selenium GitHub Test

Tags: java, maven, selenium, github, jenkins

Currently I have a GitHub Repo that contains 4 Selenium/Maven Tests. I am able to run each test individually on my local machine via **mvn test**

I have Jenkins running also on my local machine and created a maven project to pull my GitHub Repository, select the pom.xml in one of the test (P_ProfileChangeMavenTest) and then execute a test as my maven goal.

When Jenkins runs my test, it begins to go though my maven project but is not pulling up Firefox browser to interact with my test.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.profilechange</groupId>
    <artifactId>Profile</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Profile</name>
    <description>PRofile</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am fairly new to Automation and am trying to verify that everything works correctly on my local machine first before sending these tests to run on a server with a selenium grid.

All the help would be greatly appreciated since I need to get this working ASAP.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: according to your error, it says "element not visible exception". let's talk on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found works for us is using testNg to run the tests. We create an XML file with the different tests that we want run and we use

mvn test -D testng=testname.xml

TestNG is a great framework for integration style tests whereas the J Unit testing framework is more designed for unit tests.

A sample of the xml file would be something like this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name=" Report - Create New Report and Add Fields By Double Click and Filter by Right Clicking" parallel="none" verbose="1">
    <test verbose="1" name="is site available" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.somecompany.qa.seleniumautomation.PucDD">
        <methods>
          <include name="siteAvailable" />
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test verbose="1" name="Login as 'admin' 'password'" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.somecompany.qa.seleniumautomation.PucDD">
        <methods>
          <parameter name="login.user" value="admin" />
          <parameter name="login.password" value="password" />
          <include name="login" />
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test verbose="1" name="Create a new Report based on the provided data source" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.somecompany.qa.seleniumautomation.Reports">
        <methods>
            <parameter name="data.source.name" value="Orders" />    
            <include name="createNewReport"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test verbose="1" name="Add the passed fields to the report by double clicking and add the passed filters by right clicking the field." preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.company.qa.seleniumautomation.Reports">
        <methods>
            <parameter name="login.user" value="admin" />   
            <parameter name="login.password" value="password" />
            <parameter name="fields" value="Customer Number,Customer Name,Order Date,Status,Shipped Date" />
            <parameter name="filterCriteria" value="Customer Number:lte=300,Customer Number:gte=150,Product Lines:contains=a" />
            <include name="addFilters"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test verbose="1" name="Close the report" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.company.qa.seleniumautomation.Reports">
        <methods>
          <include name="close"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: This would require me to fully change my project (which I may look into but prefer not having to do). I think my main issue is Jenkins does not launch a web browser to run its test

Comment: @user2683183 Are you using Selenium RC or Web Driver?

Answer (score 0):

the jenkins job is running on it's own client. it don't have a visible UI, that's why you test failed.

you should change you test code to use Remote Webdriver or Selenium Grid

```
//need to start a selenium standalone server
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://SERVER_ADDRESS:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

refer to [Selenium Grid Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) for more detaisl

Answer (score 0):

If you start Jenkins using command line and if you run tests then you can see running tests on browser.

Command to start Jenkins using command line :
java -jar jenkins.war

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it as admin from the command prompt, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows :

1).Go to command prompt:
 type "cmd"

2).Press Ctl+Shft+Enter(to open as admin)

3).Type "Services.msc"

4).It will open the Windows Services,select "Jenkins" Service , right click & open properties and go to "Log On" tab and select "Local System Account" and select "Allow service to interact with the Desktop".

[image]

5).Press OK.

6).A dialog box will open .Click "View The Message" on the window "A program running on this computer is trying to display a message".

[image]

Now you can see the tests running on the same machine...enjoy!